# Запятая при предикативной части в середине предложения

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Дано предложение: "Но, как бы ни старался Каин вместе с остановившимся для него временем, вспомнить не удалось". Правильно ли стоят запятые?

Comment: в предложении несколько сомнительна грамматика. Как минимум частица "бы" лишняя. И/или  еще что-то. В такой ситуации говорить о правильной пунктуации затруднительно.

Answer (score 1):

*Но, **как бы ни старался Каин вместе с остановившимся для него временем**, вспомнить не удалось.*

Постановка запятой после союза НО **факультативна** и зависит от наличия паузы.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=140#pp140

5. Постановка запятой между присоединительным союзом (в начале предложения, после точки) и следующим за ним подчинительным союзом **зависит от значения союза**.

3) **после союза НО** запятая ставится **при наличии паузы между союзами и не ставится, если паузы нет**; ср.: **Но, если** далее противнику удавалось отбить атакующих, пехота снова бросалась в атаку (Сим.); **Но когда** он, опираясь на палку, вышел из штабного автобуса на площадь… ... что-то защемило в ране (Павл.);

**Примечание**

Смысл предложения не совсем ясен. Возможно, частица БЫ должна быть в обеих частях предложения или ее вообще не должно быть:

(1) *Но, **как  ни** старался Каин вместе с остановившимся для него временем, вспомнить  не удалось.*

(2) *Но, **как бы ни** старался Каин вместе с остановившимся для него временем, вспомнить **бы ему** не удалось.*